# Summing Inputs of Form and Submit Total with Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am looking to create a form. In this form the user enters the values for up to 12 numbers. The total of these numbers is updated and displayed on screen as they are entered. Then when the form is submitted, the total is submitted along with the form.

I have it working so that the total is displayed and updated, but the total is never submitted along with the form.

If I change it from type hidden to type text and manually change the total and submit the form, the total will be submitted. But if the total is changed automatically by the JavaScript it will not submit it with the form.

Comment: Need to see the whole form and code that makes the http request. I suspect because you are calculating using vanilla JS, Angular is unaware of the changes and that could be part of your problem.

Comment: But your not using AngularJS with your code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To benefit using AngularJS You need to use controller and 2-way binding
Example:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function(){
      $scope.total = 0;
      $scope.annual = 0;
    $scope.totalkWh = function totalkWh()
    {
        total = 0;
        var months = document.getElementsByName('kWh');

        for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
        {
           total += parseInt(months[i].value) || 0;
        }
         $scope.total = "Total Annual Usage: " + total + " kWh";
         $scope.annual = total;
   }
})
```

and your view will be something like

```
<input type="hidden" data-ng-model="annual" value="{{ value }}" data-ng-required="false">
<div>{{total}}</div>
```

I hope this helpful

Comment: I will edit this code if you don't do this your hidden field will not get value
`<input type="hidden" data-ng-model="annual" value="{{ annual }}" data-ng-required="false">`